# random image with a narray

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, nsarray

Hi everyone I'm french so excuse me for my english. So what I want is that a UIImageView choose between different(random) @"XXX.png" file to show it on the screen. I think we must use a NSArray or something like that. How can I do this please.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a number from 0 to x

```
  int randomval = arc4random() % x;
```

To format the number with 0 padding

```
  NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3d", randomval];
```

If the .png are not named with numbers, then you could load them into an array with the code [here](https://gist.github.com/293959).